# How to add a column from a database into a JComboBox?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to add a column from a database into a JComboBox. This is my code:

```
    public mannar() { // constructor
            initComponents();
            fillCombo();
        }
    
        private void fillCombo() {
    
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/odemetrics", "root", "");
                String sql0 = "SELECT * FROM station";
                PreparedStatement pst0 = con.prepareStatement(sql0);
                ResultSet rs = pst0.executeQuery();
    
                while (rs.next()) {
    
                    String stations = rs.getString("stname");              
                    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
                    combo.addItem(stations);
                    table_man.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));
                }
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
```

but I got only the last row of that column. That column has 348 rows. How can I fix it? Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Move the creation of the combo box instance out of the loop and everything should be fine

Comment: It's because you are initializing combo box inside loop. Move the initialization part outside the loop

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff  I got it.

Comment: @Mohammad All good!